# Control crosstab column visibility with report parameter in BIRT

Tags: birt

I need to make a crosstab column visible or hidden based on a report parameter. How can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the onPrepare event of crosstab you can do some thing like this

```
function onPrepareCell( cell, reportContext ){

    if(reportContext.getParameterValue("reportParameter") == something ){
      if( cell.getCellID() == cell#){
      cell.getStyle().setDisplay("none");
      }
 }
```

cell# is the ElementId of the cell you want to hide

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it out when I can.