# Hide summary columns on a Birt report

Tags: eclipse, report, birt

Essentially I want to [have grand total column](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iadthelp/v8r0/topic/org.eclipse.birt.doc/birt/images/xtab_layout4.gif) like the one I just linked to.

However, I want to hide the column that the grand total is based off of. For example, in reference to the picture, I would want to keep the grand total on the right without displaying the extended price column on the left.

I also tried to write a script that would hide the cells in the On Prepare event of the crosstab, but when I select the crosstab in the script tab it says "This element has no methods".

Is this possible?

Sources:

[Eclipse documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iadthelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.birt.doc%2Fbirt%2Fcrosstab.17.9.html)

[Stack Overflow question stating to use the onPrepare event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8737248/control-crosstab-column-visibility-with-report-parameter-in-birt/12817821#12817821)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you should be able to do this by selecting the column, and in the property editor below select "Visibility -> Hide Element -> For all outputs".

Comment: I actually discovered after much pain and suffering that it was an issue with the version I was using. 2.2.1 had a bug that did not allow what you described, but after updating to 2.5.2 I was able to accomplish this.

Comment: Ah, hate it when that happens. Great that you managed to niffle that out.